# Preventing Typescript class scaffolding / setup in one mocha it function from interfering with another?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing typescript tests in Mocha, and defined a test like this:

```
    describe("IsDefined", () => {
    it("should work right ...", () => {
        class Test {
        @IsDefined() p1: String = "";
        @IsDefined() p2: Date = new Date();
        @IsDefined() p3: Number = 0;
        }
```

Then inside another test within the same `describe` block I redefine the `Test` class like this:

```
    it("should have accurately mapped ValidationContext values.", () => {
        const options: ValidationOptions = {
        each: true,
        message: "Wazzzzaaaaaaapppppp????!!!!"
        };

        class Test {
        @IsDefined(options) p1: String = "";
        @IsDefined(options) p2: Date = new Date();
        @IsDefined(options) p3: Number = 0;
        }

        const instance = new Test();
```

That did not work.  Somehow the `Test` class from the earlier `it` method is still being used to create the `instance` I'm creating, so the options passed into the decorator are not seen.

If I rename the the class to `Test2` then I get the correct result, but I prefer not to have to rely on correct naming for classes used in setup.

What is the correct way to setup before each `it` method so that this does not happen?

Comment: You should try to replace `() => {` with `function(){` and see.

Comment: I have an open mocha issue for this ... the behavior could be a good thing, but only if you understand what's going on ... https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3425

Comment: Something is wrong. `it` accepts a closure and each closure has separate lexical scope. The `Test` from first scope cannot possibly interfere w `Test` from second scope unless your `@IsDefined` somehow indexes rules by name.
Please share definiion of `@IsDefined` so i can relate to problem as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually a good thing that Mocha does not try to isolate typescript class definitions to a specific testing scope.  For example decorators that run on class instances can produce invalid state if multiple definitions of the same class are loaded in the runtime.  This happened while I was working with the above, and as a result I ended up with a much better cache design.  Here it is:

```
    /**
    * If the ValidationContext instance is absent it is created, otherwise
    * the context is placed in the cache specific to the class decorated.
    * @param key 
    * @param vc
    * @throws Error if attempting to add a ValidationContext that has already been added
    * 
    * The exception thrown indicates that duplicate class definition exist in the runtime.
    */
    private static pushIfAbsent(key: string, vc: ValidationContext):void {
        if (this.cache[key] == null) {
        const validationContextMap: IValidationContextIndex = {};
        validationContextMap[vc.getSignature()]= vc;
        this.cache[key] = validationContextMap;
        } else {
        if (this.cache[key][vc.getSignature()]) {
            throw new Error(`The ValidationContainer already contains context with signature ${vc.getSignature()}.`);
        }
        this.cache[key][vc.getSignature()]=vc;
        }
    }
```

So I consider this a Mocha feature rather than a bug.  If you define the same class in multiple test cases it will produce duplicate runtime definitions and this can be used test decorator impact on state that stores the result of the decorator implementations.

So the best way to make sure that you don't have multiple runtime implementations of the same class is to define it in one place and import it like you do with all other class implementations.